# Document Width if A over B Then B is Hidden

Tags: jquery, html, width, hide, document

http://jsbin.com/iZILATE/1/edit

I have buttons on my header in JQuery Mobile. I want to hide the heading (h1) only when the anchors are displayed over the heading element, either it be low resolution, or changing view from landscape to portrait for instance.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="header ui-bar-c" id="head1" data-role='header'>
    <div id="gentags" class="ui-btn-left">
        <a id="htmltag" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">&lt;&gt;&lt;/&gt;</a>
        <a id="csstag1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">{}</a>
        <a id="colon" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">:</a>
        <a id="semicolon" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">;</a>
        <a id="csstag2" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">:;</a>
        <a id="jstag1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">()</a>
        <a id="jstag2" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">("")</a>
        <a id="function" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">function(){}</a>
    </div>

    <h1>Text Website Name</h1>
    <a href="#menupanel" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn-right">Bars</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Put your code in the question, do not use links all alone.

Comment: Updated with the code

Comment: It can be done but it is not so easy. By default the header has 30% of margin left, so you calculate on resize if the button container is bigger than the 30% of the screen width. But... if you hide the header you will lose the UI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script can be of help to guide you:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
   $(window).bind('resize', function() {
      var $btns = $('#headbtns'),
      btnsWidth = $btns.width(),
      width     = $(window).width();
      if ((btnsWidth / width) > 0.3)
         $('.ui-title').hide();
   else
         $('.ui-title').show();
   });
});
```

Here we are detecting if the width of the buttons container is bigger than the 30% of the view-port width. By default, the header in jQuery mobile has 30% of margin in x-axis.

Although, it works as I explained it, but it will not precise to detect the collision of the buttons containers with the text in the header. To do that, it requires some dirty tricks...